# HAL-based REST API with download file endpoint

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-hateoas

I'm developing a HAL-based REST API with Spring boot. I need a endpoint in my controller, that sends a file to the client. There are some examples on SO, but it doesn't work because of the following Exception:

```
Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: 
  org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write 
  content: No serializer found for class java.io.ByteArrayInputStream and no properties 
  discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable 
  SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) through reference chain: 
  org.springframework.core.io.ByteArrayResource["inputStream"]); 
  nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: 
  No serializer found for class java.io.ByteArrayInputStream 
  and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, 
  disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: 
  org.springframework.core.io.ByteArrayResource["inputStream"])
```

My Spring application:

```
@EnableHypermediaSupport(type = HAL)
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyServer {
    public static String CURIE_NAMESPACE = "myNS";

    public @Bean
    CurieProvider curieProvider() {
        return new DefaultCurieProvider(CURIE_NAMESPACE, new UriTemplate("/docs/html5/{rel}.html"));
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpMessageConverters customConverters() {
        ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter arrayHttpMessageConverter = new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter();
        return new HttpMessageConverters(arrayHttpMessageConverter);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyServer.class, args);
    }
}
```

My Controller class looks like this:

```
@BasePathAwareController
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
public class MyController implements ResourceProcessor<RepositoryLinksResource> {
    public static final String ENDPOINT_URL = "/myResource";
    ...

    @RequestMapping(value = ENDPOINT_URL + "/download", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<ByteArrayResource> downloadAttachment(){
        ...
        // get from my service the resource
        MyClass myResource = myService.getResource();

        String filename = myResource.getFilename();
        String contentType = myResource.getContentType();

        try (InputStream myStream = myResource.getStream()) {
            HttpHeaders respHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
            respHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.valueOf(contentType));
            respHeaders.setContentDispositionFormData("attachment", filename);

            byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(myStream);
            ByteArrayResource byteResource = new ByteArrayResource(bytes);

            return ResponseEntity.ok()
                   .headers(respHeaders)
                   .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType(contentType))
                   .body(byteResource);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        ...
        }
    }
}
```

I am adding the custom converter bean as shown in my application code. But i think due to this isssue [@EnableHypermediaSupport is not compatible with Spring Boot's Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder #333](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/issues/333) it is not working!?

spring-boot version: 1.5.2.RELEASE

spring-hateoas version: 0.23.0.RELEASE

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You have a mismatch between your message converter and your content type. Either use a ResourceHttpMessageConverter or change your return type to ResponseEntity<byte[]>.